# Is it possible to paste html into CKEditor (using js/jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

So what I'm trying to do is this: I have multiple divs where I paste content generated by CKEditor, this is easy and it works. So every one of those divs contains some html generated by the editor.

Let's say that that is `var content = <p>......</p>`,

now I want this content to show up in the editor. I've got it out of the editor using `editor.getData()`, but now I want to put that same data back into the editor, is that possible in any way?

Comment: If there is `getData`, and you have experience using any API at all, your gut should tell you that there should be a [setData](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData).

Comment: Yeah, just spent some time looking at that and hitting myself in the head for missing that... going to try it now :)